# Como sumar 12 horas a la fecha actual, guardarlo en un acumulador y volver a sumar en php

Tags: php, date

estoy aprendiendo php y tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Monterrey');
$f = date (" d\of F\of Y, H:i");
echo $f, "<BR>";
setlocale(LC_TIME, "es_Mx.utf8");
$f2=strftime("Today is %A %d of %B of %G and is %H:%M %p");
echo $f2."<BR>";
$time=strtotime("31 january 2017");
$f3 = date ("j/n/Y", $time);
echo $f3."<BR>";
$f4=strftime("%A %d of %B of %G and is %H:%M %p", time() + 12*60*60);
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
echo $f4."<BR>";
}
?>
```

y me imprime esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me debería de imprimir esto:

Thursday 16 of february of 2017 and is 07:21AM

Thursday 16 of february of 2017 and is 07:21PM

Friday 17 of february of 2017 and is 07:21AM

y así sucesivamente, que le puedo agregar a mi código para que este completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras

```
$f4=strftime("%A %d of %B of %G and is %H:%M %p", time() + 12*60*60);
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  echo $f4."<BR>";
}
```

tu variable `$f4` es definida una sola vez, y permanece con esa fecha para siempre. Luego en el bucle `for` la imprimes 10 veces.

Lo que debes hacer es almacenar la fecha antes de entrar al bucle y modificarla dentro de este, en cada iteración:

```
$tiempo = time();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
   $tiempo = $tiempo + 12*60*60*$i; 
   $f4=strftime("%A %d of %B of %G and is %H:%M %p", $tiempo);
   echo $f4."<BR>";
}
```